# Import database from Magento2.3 to Magento2.4

Tags: database, migration, magento2.3.2, magento2.4.2

I'm new with Magento. Now I want to upgrade Magento from 2.3 to 2.4 and I already make a seperated 2.4 sites. but on my 2.3 is still using so the order is continue running.

I want to know that if I can dump database with all table from Magento2.3 to Magento 2.4 or not? The step that I think is move database into new site and change database connection in Magento2.4 .env file. Can I do that or I have to export each table myself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do the following things.

1. Make the coppy of Magento 2.3 database.
2. Now Change the env.php file of Magento 2.4 and connected that to newly create copy database.
3. Run the upgrade, deploy and all the commands.

Comment: I already to that. but their are some problem with product that I add on Magento2.3 after making seperated 2.4 site. After change DB in env file and do the upgrade and cache thing. It's not show the custom block class on the new product page. but on the old product page, it's showed

Comment: Confirm that things not required any file changes like install extension, or do the conflict etc.

Comment: yes, it's just phtml file

Comment: Then do those things into the 2.4 and then check.

Comment: I have to add new product on 2.4 database right?

Comment: After making the copy, whatever things you perform on magento2.3 site need to do manually on Magento2.4